# How to subscribe to a view render event?

Tags: views, javascript

I'm writing a module that will inject javascript into the page when a view is rendered. The contents of the javascript will depend on the results returned in the view, so ideally I would have access to that. I'm trying to use event subscriptions to do this. I have the getSubscribedEvents function set up but I'm trying to find a view render event to subscribe to. Is there such an event I can use?

Comment: Is it an Ajax view?

Comment: @cilefen yes, it uses Ajax

Comment: `Drupal.behaviors` fires all its child methods whenever AJAX loads new content into the DOM https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview#s-example-using-drupalbehaviors